# Fail to print through IIS using Impersonation in windows server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, .net, iis, printing, impersonation

I'm trying to access the network printers by doing impersonation using below code to print a pdf document from IIS (WCF application). Since my wcf application run under 'LocalSystem' app pool identity, i need to do the impersonation.

```
      [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
      public class Impersonation : IDisposable
      {

        private readonly SafeTokenHandle _handle;
        private readonly WindowsImpersonationContext _context;
    bool disposed = false;

    // constants from winbase.h
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT35 = 1;
    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40 = 2;
    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;

    public Impersonation(ImpersonateUserDetails user) : this(user.Domain, user.UserName, user.Password)
    { }
    public Impersonation(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        // if domain name was blank, assume local machine
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
            domain = System.Environment.MachineName;

        var ok = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
                       LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out this._handle);
        if (!ok)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser returned error code {0}.", errorCode));
        }

        this._context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            this._context.Dispose();
            this._handle.Dispose();
        }           
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~Impersonation()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true) { }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }
}

public class ImpersonateUserDetails
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

But Printing doesn't work with this impersonation though I can list out the network printers but when I send the document to the printer it doesn't print. it shows with Size empty in the print queue. Any Idea please???

Here is the printing code from Microsoft which I'm calling under impersonation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx

code example:

```
using (new Impersonation(domain, username, password)) 
{ 
  //printing code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Can you run the application under iis express and verify if it is working ? I just want to isolate if it is IIS security sandbox which is causing this. Because IIS has a security sandbox and System.Drawing may not work completely

Comment: can't, because server doesn't have iis express. But yes, If I do run the application on my local box (windows 7 & IIS 7.5) it runs successfully. Everything works as expected. But when I deploy the same application in Windows Server 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5) it doesn't print (Doesn't give any exception or error as well), rather it document goes to print queue but size says nothing.